# android studio isnt working (build.gradle issue)

Tags: android, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

[build.gradle error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7N9E.png)

I am facing above issue. when I try to install **artifacts** and sync project it installs but nothing happens after that.
I am using **android studio 2.3.3**
can proxy block the installation ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think the sdk is not installed properly

Comment: Connect to Internet and Click on Issue coming on Logcat

Comment: Post you `build.gradle` file. And do not post error in image.

Answer (score 0):

Try to ***Install Repository and sync project*** option for each error. This was worked for me.

Comment: I tried doing that but nothing happened and same error popped up.